# Create cookie for div

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>


<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.3.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.3.0/firebaseui.css" />
  <link href="auth.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>



 <div id="container">
      <h3></h3>
      <div id="loading"></div>
      <div id="loaded" class="hidden">
        <div id="main">
          <div id="user-signed-in" class="hidden">
            <div id="user-info">
              <div id="photo-container">
                <img id="photo">
              </div>
              <div id="name"></div>
              <div id="email"></div>
              <div id="phone"></div>
               <script>document.cookie = document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML;
             </script>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <p>
              <button id="sign-out">Sign Out</button>
              <button id="delete-account">Delete account</button>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="user-signed-out" class="hidden">
            <h4>You are signed out.</h4>
            <div id="firebaseui-spa">
              <h3></h3>
              <div id="firebaseui-container"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="auth.js"></script>

</body>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Place this inside the HTML head; don't use async defer for now -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        
        var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
        
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        
        // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
        var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push());
      </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      var lat, lng;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 18

        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var pos = {lat: lat, lng: lng };
                _setGeoFire();
              var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var x = document.cookie;
  var markerLabel = x;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]


    },
    map: map,
    label: markerLabel
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
    return function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
  }(data)));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
          
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Current Location');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
      function _setGeoFire(){
    geoFire.set("User", [lat, lng]).then(()=>{
            console.log("Location added");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2nPlSt_nM7PSKD8So8anbUbBYICFWcCA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I created a phone number authentication system. The user enters their phone number and it sends a code to the phone that the user enters that code on the site and that's how they are authenticated. I want to capture what number they type into the site. I created a cookie under the div 
"phone" to capture the phone number. I want to show all the user's location using markers on a google map and I want the google map marker to display the individual phone number assigned to that user so in my other file I created a variable that had the value of the cookie. I then made the marker label that variable and I thought the phone number would appear but nothing shows up for the marker label.I don't know what to do, if anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I realized that you used `document.cookie = document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML;` when you should have used `document.cookie = "PhoneNumber="+document.getElementById("phone").value;` to grab the value of the input. So all you have to do to fix your problem is change `.innerHTML` to `.value` and declare a name to the cookie or it won't be saved as a cookie.

Using `.innerHTML` will grab all the HTML inside the element, while `.value` will grab what the user has typed / selected.

Hope this helps your problem.
[image: Working Cookie Save]

Comment: The marker now has a label but it says undefined instead of displaying the phone number

Comment: Whoops! Forgot to declare a name for the cookie, without one it won't be saved correctly! I edited my answer with the correct one, thanks for the catch!

Comment: I declared a name for the cookie just like how you did and now the label says PhoneNumber=undefined; undefined=

Comment: I don't know why this is showing up, if anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post some of the html for the phone number? You posted no html with any inputs which makes it hard to see what is wrong.

Comment: I posted the HTML. I used google firebase so the phone number box is pre-made with google firebase code it uses this thing called firebase auth UI

Comment: Are you capturing the value of an input made by another script? If so, it might be an iFrame or something else.